# Flat modules on Stacks Project.

Tags: commutative-algebra, soft-question, modules

I have been reading through a bit of the material from the Stacks project, and there is a statement that I cannot make sense of.  Lemma 10.36.19(7) states:

> Let $R$ be a ring.
>
> (7)  Suppose $R\rightarrow A$ is a ring map, and $M$ is an $A$-module.  Then $M$ is a flat $R$-module if and only if the localization $M_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is a flat $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$-module (with $\mathfrak{p}=R\cap\mathfrak{m}$) for all maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}$ of $A$.

I just don't understand the "with $\mathfrak{p}=R\cap\mathfrak{m}$" part: $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal of $A$, and $A$ does not necessarily intersect with $R$ at all, so what sense does it make to intersect $\mathfrak{m}$ with $R$?  Surely not all $A$-modules are flat if $A\cap R=\emptyset$, right?  Am I just missing something simple here (like: do they simply mean $\text{Im}(f)\cap\mathfrak{m}$, where $f$ is the ring map given in the statement?), or is something amiss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $R \cap \mathfrak m$ is sometimes used to denote the inverse image of $\mathfrak m$ in $R$. It is a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ of $A$.

There is a canonical morphism $R_{\mathfrak p} \to A_{\mathfrak m}$, and the $A_{\mathfrak m}$-module $M_{\mathfrak m}$ acquires an $R_{\mathfrak p}$-module structure via this map.

Comment: Ah, that would make sense!  So it is something simple afterall.  :D  (I'll accept your answer once it lets me in 8, or so, minutes)

Comment: @Guest I think that 90% of the difficulty we face when learning mathematics is actually the difficulty of understanding what someone else means, and not the difficulty of understanding what they understand!

Comment: Haha, definitely!